# C++ openmp parallelize std::vector loop

Tags: c++11, openmp

I have an issue with openmp. I'm trying to parallelize following C++ for loop, allWires is a std::vector of type Wire*, and Wire is a class defined by myself. initProcess(const Lib&) is member function of class Wire, library is an object of Lib, which is also defined by myself.
There is no memory sharing in all Wire objects, and I expect this piece of code could be perfectly parallelized, but I didn't see any performance improvement by using openmp. Did I do wrong with openmp?

```
uint32_t wireCnt = allWires.size();
#pragma omp parallel for
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < wireCnt; ++i)
{
    allWires[i]->initProcess (library);
}
```

Comment: Could be a number of things. For example, how many cores are you using and how big is `wireCnt`?

Comment: @AndyG, The wireCnt is about 100K, and this piece of code takes about 8s without openmp. I didn't specify number of cores to use, but there are 8 cores on the machine.

Comment: How did you measure the time?

Comment: Which compiler? What compile options did you use? Are you sure you enabled OpenMP?

Comment: @Zboson I used gcc 4.7.2, with -Ofast. I ran my program under gdb, and I saw it generated 7 threads.

Comment: @liwuxi, did you use `-fopenmp`? I recommend compiling with `-Wall` because otherwise you don't know if your pragmas are ignored or if you typed a construct incorrectly (I wasted a lot of time once because of a silly typo in a pragma which `-Wall` would have warned me about).

Comment: You should answer @HristoIliev question as well. How did you measure the time?  Did you use `clock()` or e.g. `omp_get_wtime()`?

Comment: @HristoIliev I used unix/liunx time command as well as clock(), they show the same results.

Comment: @Zboson yes I added -fopenmp, and I can see multi-threads are generated  in gdb

Comment: Use `omp_get_wtime()`. If it still shows the same result, then you might want to use a performance tool like Intel VTune (commercial tool, might require paid license)